# find out if the of the callback function is an ES6 arrow

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

Because of the big difference in the context difference between normal and ES6 arrow functions I'd like to be able to find out which one was received on a callback fn.

`typeof` will [return](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iqa0nifh/) `function` for both. Is there any way to distinguish?

Comment: Please don't do this, if you're designing an API, it should work consistently with both. Think of users refactoring code for instance, would you realistically expect the signature of a function to change based on the function passed? I would not. Also keep in mind that any detection method would likely fail with transpiled arrow functions, so your code would change behavior depending on the environment it was running in.

Comment: Why do you want to be able to tell the difference?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference for the receiver of the callback. You can simply call all types of callbacks.

Comment: @Paul: No! Arrow functions do inherit from `Function.prototype` as well, so you can use those methods on them (just like you can call them like methods), it's just that they ignore what they were called on. It does not make the slightest bit of difference to the caller.

Answer (score 6):

Arrow functions can't be used as constructors and show `typeof arrowFunc.prototype` as `undefined`, whereas a non-arrow function shows `"object".

Comment: Confirmed working in Chromebook Chrome 51.0.2704.103 with `x = function(){return 1;}; y=(()=>1); console.log(typeof x.prototype, typeof y.prototype);` yielding `object,  undefined`

Comment: It's returning `object` for both, in [this fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iqa214ua/).

Comment: hmmm I guess it won't work on Babel, since it's compiling to normal functions :/ but thanks for the solution, seems to be the best way when the compiler is not an issue.

Comment: @deniloprates This one works...  https://jsfiddle.net/9tsL2dgz/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Function.toString()` to return a string representation of the source code of the function, then look for an arrow (`=>`) in the string.

```
var arrowFunc = x => 2 * x
var regFunc = function (x) {return 2 * x}

arrowFunc.toString().indexOf("=>") // 2
regFunc.toString().indexOf("=>") // -1
```

Comment: wouldn't this detect a non arrow function with a nested arrow function, or a default parameter value of  an arrow function, as an arrow function?

Comment: I guess it would detect a nested arrow function, which could be prevented by evaluating the return of `indexOf` in some cases. Not sure about the default parameter value though, they don't use `=>` do they?

Comment: Only if the default value is a function and defined in-line as an arrow function...

Comment: Ah, good point. Use carefully...